# If $M$ is a diagonal matrix, what is $M^\infty$?

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices

We have the matrix:
$$M = \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
0.8&0&0\\
0&1.2&0\\
0&0&1\\\end{array}\right]$$
I have got three eigenvectors:
              (1   0   0)
              (0,  1,  0)
              (0   0   1)

And this is my task:
We are interested in what happens to the system when we repeat the stepwise
process several times. To get an idea of the development of the system we compute
some powers of $M$.
c) Compute $M^2, M^3, M^4$ and $M^5$. What can you say about $M^n$ when $n \to \infty$ in this case?
Any suggestions? I do not fully believe my way of approaching this problem is the right way.

Comment: There's absolutely no need to ask same question twice.

Comment: Sorry, I got a manditory submission due tommorrow. One could say I am kind of taking advantage off this website.

Comment: Could anyone tell me the reasoning behind this theorem, or post a link of it on wikipedia or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\lim _{n \to \infty} M^n = \lim _{n \to \infty}\left[\begin{array}{rrr}
0.8^n&0&0\\
0&1.2^n&0\\
0&0&1^n\\\end{array}\right]$$

Comment: I get that but is it wrong using (xn, yn, zn)=M^n(x0, y0, z0), then inputing the eigenvalues and eigenvectors for (x0, y0, z0) respectively?

Comment: that will work - you get $M^n (1,0,0) = 0.8^n (1,0, 0)$ and  $M^n (0,1,0) = 1.2^n (0,1, 0)$ and  $M^n (0,0,1) = 1.0^n (0,0, 1)$

Comment: Okay lets say I have this equilibrium state: $$=\begin{Bmatrix} 
-0.2x_s\\ 
0.2y_s\\
0
\end{Bmatrix}=\begin{Bmatrix} 
0\\ 
0\\
0
\end{Bmatrix}$$

Comment: i would love for you to help me out on this one: The attractor basin for this equilibrium state is given as all states (x, y, z) such that M^n*(x, y, z) →(xs, ys, zs) when n → ∞ e) Determine the attractor basin for the equilibrium state (xs, ys, zs) you found in exercise d). d being the one on my previous comment

Comment: $(a,b,c)$ will diverge unless $b=0$, otherwise $(a,0,c) \to (0,0,c)$ so the basin for the final state $(0,0,0)$ is $(a,0,0)$

Comment: $$M = \left[\begin{array}{rrr}
-0.2&0&0.1\\
0&0.2&-0.1\\
0&0&0\\\end{array}\right]$$

Comment: For this one then?

Comment: $$M^n(av_1+bv_2+cv_3) = a\lambda_1^n v_1 + b\lambda_2^n v_2 + c\lambda_3^n v_3 $$